# polymorphic relationship on a many-to-many table

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I currently have 4 tables

**students**

**sessions**

**session_student**

**prices**

**prices** is a polymorphic relation table using morphOne.

is it possible to add a relationship between **session_student** and **prices** using eloquent?

Comment: How do we know Foreign Keys and the relation between these tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*is it possible to add a relationship between session_student and prices using eloquent?*

Of course it is. Make pivot model `SessionStudent` and continue making relations between that model and `Price` model. Of course, you will need pivot table between those which should be called `price_session_student`.

```
class SessionStudent extends Pivot
{
     // adequate code here i.e. $fillables etc.

    public function prices()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Price::class);
    }
}

// php artisan make:migration create_table_price_session_student

class Price extends Model
{
    //
    public function sessionStudents()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(SessionStudent::class);
    }
}
```

Note that session student extends Pivot class. [Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#defining-custom-intermediate-table-models).